# Building a ListView with both API and AsyncStorage Data

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native

To build my react native ListView, I need to pull data from two places, from a network APi and from AsyncStorage (like AppCache). The data from AsyncStorage may or may not be there, but it needs to return something either way (e.g. "not found")

Here's a gist of the current version, which works except for retrieving the cachedOn date ([Line 47](https://gist.github.com/geirman/1901d4b1bfad42ec6d65#file-aircraftlist-js-L47))
https://gist.github.com/geirman/1901d4b1bfad42ec6d65#file-aircraftlist-js-L47, which is where I believe the secret sauce goes.

I think this is probably something any ReactJS developer could probably answer, though the example is React Native specific.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this? I am trying to solve the same sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, but I was never very happy with the solution. You can see my code on github https://github.com/geirman/RepairMaps/ Thanks for bringing attention to this question again though. Looks like there's a couple fresh answers to review!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems quite complex, because there are multiple levels of asynchronicity in play: fetching data, reading/writing the cache, and rendering list rows. In cases like this, breaking down the problem to smaller components usually helps.

I couldn't easily get the example code running, so I'm using a simplified example.

First, let's wrap the cache into a neat interface, so we don't need to think about the `AsyncStorage` semantics while working with it:

```js
const aircraftCache = {
  // returns promise of cached aircraft, or null if not found
  getAircraft(aircraftId) {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem(aircraftId).then(data => (
      data ? JSON.parse(data) : null
    ));
  },

  // caches given aircraft object with a fresh cachedOn date
  // and returns a promise of the cached aircraft
  setAircraft(aircraftId, aircraft) {
    const cached = {...aircraft, cachedOn: new Date()};
    return AsyncStorage.setItem(aircraftId, JSON.stringify(cached)).then(() => cached);
  },

  // clears given aircraft from cache and return Promise<null>
  clearAircraft(aircraftId) {
    return AsyncStorage.removeItem(aircraftId).then(() => null);
  }
}
```

Then, let's limit the `AircraftList` responsibility to just displaying the list of data, loading indicator etc, and extract the row rendering to a separate component:

```js
class AircraftList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    aircraft_list: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      reg_number: PropTypes.string,
      ti_count: PropTypes.number
    }))
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    this.state = {
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.aircraft_list),
      isLoading: false,
      showingCache: false
    };
  }

  aircraftLoaded(aircraft) {
    this.setState({isLoading: false});
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'TI Lookup',
      component: TrackedItemIndex,
      passProps: {aircraft_object: aircraft}
    });
  }

  renderRow(aircraft) {
    return (
      <AircraftRow
        reg_number={aircraft.reg_number}
        ti_count={aircraft.ti_count}
        loading={() => this.setState({isLoading: true})}
        loaded={this.aircraftLoaded.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    // simplified view
    return(
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The individual row rendering, fetching and cache manipulation can then be encapsulated into `AircraftRow` component:

```js
class AircraftRow extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    reg_number: PropTypes.string,
    ti_count: PropTypes.number,
    loading: PropTypes.func,
    loaded: PropTypes.func
  }

  state = { cachedOn: null };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.loadDetails = this.loadDetails.bind(this);
    this.clearDetails = this.clearDetails.bind(this);
    this.setCachedOn = this.setCachedOn.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // when component is loaded, look up the cached details and
    // set the cachedOn timestamp into state
    aircraftCache.getAircraft(this.props.reg_number).then(this.setCachedOn);
  }

  loadDetails() {
    const id = this.props.reg_number;
    // notify parent that loading has started
    if (this.props.loading) {
      this.props.loading(id);
    }

    // fetch and cache the data
    this.fetchDetails(id)
      .then((aircraft) => {
        // notify parent that loading has finished
        if (this.props.loaded) {
          this.props.loaded(aircraft);
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
  }

  fetchDetails(id) {
    // get details from the api, and fall back to the cached copy
    return Api.getTrackedItems(id)
      .then(aircraft => aircraftCache.setAircraft(id, aircraft))
      .then(this.setCachedOn)
      .catch(() => aircraftCache.getAircraft(id));
  }

  clearDetails() {
    // clear item from cache and update local state with null aircraft
    const id = this.props.reg_number;
    aircraftCache.clearAircraft(id).then(this.setCachedOn);
  }

  setCachedOn(aircraft) {
    // update local state (aircraft can be null)
    this.setState({ cachedOn: aircraft ? aircraft.cachedOn.toString() : null })
    return aircraft;
  }

  render() {
    // simplified view
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.reg_number}</Text>
        <Text>{this.props.ti_count}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.cachedOn}</Text>
        <Text onPress={this.loadDetails}>Load details</Text>
        <Text onPress={this.clearDetails}>Clear details</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

For my money, this view still does too much. I would recommend looking into state management libraries such as Redux or MobX to further simplify the code - although they come with their own set of complexities, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way of doing this is via `id mapping`.

I can see that your response gives an unique `id` for each item. So, store the time-stamp based on the same `ids` in your local storage. When you map through the items of the result from the api get the `id` of the item and passe it to the `getItem()` of the local storage. This will return you the time for that `id`

```
const randomTime = [{
  id: 1,
  date: '05-Jun-2032 14:37:11'
}, {
  id: 2,
  date: '30-Jun-2006 00:02:27'
}, {
  id: 4,
  date: '22-Aug-1996 02:47:28'
}, {
  id: 6,
  date: '04-Jan-1991 23:27:15'
}]

const preProcessLocalStorage = () => {
  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('date')) //read data from local storage
  const obj = {}
  data.forEach((el) => {
    obj[el.id] = el //convert into ids as keys object for better data retrieval 
  })
  return obj
}
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
    }
    this.apiData = []
    this.localData = []
    localStorage.setItem('date', JSON.stringify(randomTime)) //set Local data
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.localData = preProcessLocalStorage()
    $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .done((data) => {
      this.apiData = data
      this.setState({loading: false})
    })
  }

  render(){
    if(this.state.loading) return false

    const list = this.apiData.map((el) => {
      const time = this.localData[el.id] //find local data based on the api data id
      return <div>
        <h1>{el.id} - {el.title}</h1>
        <h4>{time || '-'}</h4>
      </div>
    })

    return <div>{list}</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```